# How to load a txt.file into an existing object?

Tags: java, object, text, bufferedreader, bufferedwriter

I've tried for the past couple day to do this. I've search and done copies of it, but none of them works, I've tried just easy loads. but none them works anyways.

```
public class Data
{
String Name;
 int Points;
 int Heart, Next;

 public Data(String N,int A,int V,int P)
  
{     Name = N;
   Next = A;
   Heart = V;
  Points = P;

   }
 }
```

I save them like this

```
bw.write(Dat[j].Name + " " + Dat[j].Next + "" + Dat[j].Heart + " " + Dat[j].Points);
```

After that there is a function that saves the data of the object and place it as a text.file which is "Players.txt" and ends up like this
For example:

> HECTOR 0 3 0
>
> Mary 0 3 0
>
> JOHN 0 3 0
>
> Victor 0 3 0

Now this is a Data array,being Data Dat[] = new Data [Max]; and there is a counter of "J" everytime like a simple object.All I want when the program start is to load the whole data that is in the text file and put it as this object.

```
    public static void Scoreboard() 
   { Loading(); // this suppose to be the function to load the data
        f(j > 0)
            {   
        for(int i=0; i<j; i++)
                {   
                    
    Dat[j].Show("Number"+(j+1)); // .Show is a function in the object Data    
    
                 }//for
          
            }//if
            else System.out.print("No users");
            return;
        }// Scoreboard
```

I'm pretty new to java, and I really dont understand the buffered reader and writer, I'd appreciate some help thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Quick Update I did it by myself whoever wondering here is my code. (its on spanish)

```
 public static void Loading()
       {

String Nombre;
int Vida;
int Puntuacion;
int Aprobado;
File f = new File(ruta);
        try
        {   /*Si existe el fichero*/
            if(f.exists())
            {   /*Abre un flujo de lectura a el fichero*/
                BufferedReader Flee= new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Jugadores.txt"));
                String str=null;
                /*Lee el fichero linea a linea hasta llegar a la ultima*/
                ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
                while((str=Flee.readLine())!=null)
                {   /*Imprime la linea leida*/
                    lines.add(str);
                    String[] linesArray = lines.toArray(new String[lines.size()]);
                }//WHILE
                /*Cierra el flujo*/

                for(int j=0; j<=lines.size();j = j + 4){
                 Nombre= lines.get(j);
                 Aprobado= Integer.parseInt(lines.get(j+1));
                 Vida=  Integer.parseInt(lines.get(j+2));
                 Puntuacion= Integer.parseInt(lines.get(j+3));

                Dat[cp] = new Datos(Nombre,Aprobado,Vida,Puntuacion);
                cp ++;
                }





                Flee.close();
            }
            else
                System.out.println("Fichero No Existe");
        }//try
        catch (Exception ex)
        {   /*Captura un posible error y le imprime en pantalla*/
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }//catch
}
```

I made this into an ArrayList line by line, Sure, you need your text file to be like for example :
HECTOR

3

0

3

Cheers